# How to check if the database is empty in windows phone?

Tags: c#, database, windows-phone-7

I'm using local database(in isolated storage of windows phone),in my windows phone app.
I'm in situation to check if the database is empty or not, and i have to take corresponding actions.
The below code shows the declaration of my DataBase,

```
using(MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext(strConnectionString))
 {
    if (db.DatabaseExists() == false)
      {
         db.CreateDatabase();
      }
 }
```

How should i check if my database is empty??

Comment: There is no method available out of the box. You can try iterating through the tables and check the content. Or check the database file size.

Comment: What do you mean by empty database? No tables or no data in tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check count of items in a table:

```
using(MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext(strConnectionString))
 {
    if (db.DatabaseExists() == false)
      {
         db.CreateDatabase();
      }

   if(db.Table1.Count() == 0) MessageBox.Show("Table is empty");

 }
```

You can also execute a query to get list of tables:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    DataTable schema = connection.GetSchema("Tables");
    List<string> TableNames = new List<string>();
    foreach (DataRow row in schema.Rows)
    {
        TableNames.Add(row[2].ToString());
    }

    if(TableNames.Count == 0) MessageBox.Show("No table exists in the database.");
}
```